# FormData with graphql-request

Tags: javascript, graphql, form-data, express-graphql

I am using [graphql-request](https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-request) for graphQL queries at my frontend part (react). Server side using express-graphql. I have some ideas to handle that on backend side (your suggestions will be appreciated too), but searching how to handle frontend part.

Is it possible to send a FormData (image in my case) inside [graphql-request](https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-request) query? Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

Per [their documentation](https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-request), this is the format:

```
const client = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, { headers: {} })
client.request(query, variables).then(data => console.log(data))
```

GraphQL doesn't easily handle image uploads, it probably would be easier to [upload them elsewhere and send the image URL to your graphql server](https://medium.com/@danielbuechele/file-uploads-with-graphql-and-apollo-5502bbf3941e).

You could do something like this:

```
yourClient.request(query, { id:1, imgURL:'http://foobar.com' })
.then(data => doSomethingWithData(data))
```

Comment: Thinking about such a solution too. Too much problems with image uploading directly through graphQL. Thanks for the answer!